# What is the year in this circumstance?

Tags: meaning

The context of this post is coming from [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/43813/what-does-endogeneity-of-the-industry-structure-means).
There is a sentence:

> *w<sub>kj</sub>* is the share of the three-digit SIC industry *j*’s exports from country *k* to any other country *k* out of all of the exports from industry *j* in country *k* in 1990

I am wondering whether it also means (see added bold words) "*w<sub>kj</sub>* is the share of the three-digit SIC industry *j*’s exports from country *k* to any other country *k* **in 1990** out of all of the exports from industry *j* in country *k* in 1990"

Comment: The year is 1990 either way.

Comment: @TinfoilHat so, you mean my last sentence is correct in this specific case ?

Comment: Yes, either position in the sentence means the same proportion.

Comment: @YosefBaskin . Thank you, it makes sense now.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. And also, now that I read it again, it is probably better — it erases any doubt about the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question the use of 1990 is due to the *example* itself and not that year in particular. They are using a year in the past to compare and make a point about more recent years.

The use of the year 1990 is also detailed in the answer under number 2.

"...Consequently, they also mean it in more narrow way that it would mean that in their regression of margins on those leniency laws the leniency laws would be correlated with error term. In fact, this is why Dong says that they dealt with it by using leniency index from 1990s - **using past ('lagged') values instead of contemporaneous one's is a common econometric technique** to deal with endogeneity in an empirical model."

The use of multiple subscripts chasing around various meanings goes back to Einstein's General Theory of Relativity where he used tensors and came up with a few shortcut conventions of necessity.

Comment: so, you mean that I added in 1990 in my question is correct in this specific case, please let me know if I explain you wrongly.

Comment: @Phuc Nguyen I cannot quite understand your comment. I think your original question is suitable.